# How can I compile multiple smart contracts in a single compile.js file?

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, nodejs, compilation

There is another post on this question but I don't find it useful enough so I thought I should ask again. In my compile.js file, I'm taking each smart contract's complied code and put it in a respective build file. I'm dealing with three contracts at the same time and using solidity 0.5.0. My compile file works for a single smart contract but it doesn't work for multiple smart contracts. My approach was to duplicate the same lines of code that were used to compile the first smart contract.

Is there a better way to improve the code below? or would putting all the contracts in a single solidity file work?

This is my compile.js

```
/*
Purpose: compile specific contracts and puts their output in a build file 
Updates build files whenever the contracts are updated 
*/
const path = require('path'); 
const solc = require('solc'); 
const fs = require('fs-extra'); 

// Deletes content of build folder 
const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname,'build'); 
fs.removeSync(buildPath); 

// Read content in contracts folder 
const registerContracttPath = path.resolve(__dirname,'contracts', 'Register.sol'); 
const source = fs.readFileSync(registerContracttPath, 'utf8'); 

//complie the source of the file & pull the contracts property from the compiler
// Have to use var input for solidity version 0.5.0 and up 
//Register.sol 
var input = {
    language: 'Solidity',
    sources: {
        'Register.sol' : {
            content: source
        }
    },
    settings: {
        outputSelection: {
            '*': {
                '*': [ '*' ]
            }
        }
    }
};
//BottleProduction.sol
var input1 = {
    language: 'Solidity',
    sources: {
        'BottleProduction.sol' : {
            content: source
        }
    },
    settings: {
        outputSelection: {
            '*': {
                '*': [ '*' ]
            }
        }
    }
};

//Tracking.sol
var input2 = {
    language: 'Solidity',
    sources: {
        'Tracking.sol' : {
            content: source
        }
    },
    settings: {
        outputSelection: {
            '*': {
                '*': [ '*' ]
            }
        }
    }
}; 

const output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));
const output1 = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input1)));
const output2 = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input2)));

//creates build folder 
fs.ensureDirSync(buildPath); 

//Put output of contract in a build file 
fs.outputJsonSync(
    path.resolve(buildPath, 'Register.json'), 
   {
    abi: output.contracts['Register.sol']['Register']["abi"],
    bytecode: output.contracts['Register.sol']['Register']["evm"]["bytecode"]["object"]
   },
   {
       spaces: 2,
       EOL: "\n"
   }
); 

fs.outputJsonSync(
    path.resolve(buildPath, 'BottleProduction.json'), 
   {
    abi: output1.contracts['BottleProduction.sol']['BottleProduction']["abi"],
    bytecode: output1.contracts['BottleProduction.sol']['BottleProduction']["evm"]["bytecode"]["object"]
   },
   {
       spaces: 2,
       EOL: "\n"
   }
); 


fs.outputJsonSync(
    path.resolve(buildPath, 'Tracking.json'), 
   {
    abi: output2.contracts['Tracking.sol']['Tracking']["abi"],
    bytecode: output2.contracts['Tracking.sol']['Tracking']["evm"]["bytecode"]["object"]
   },
   {
       spaces: 2,
       EOL: "\n"
   }
);
```

Comment: When you say _it doesn't work for multiple smart contracts_ what exactly do you mean? What does _work_ imply? For the code I'd suggest to use functions to divide the logic and avoid copy+paste.

Comment: To work, it should import the abi and the byte code of each complied smart contract into a respective build file (Each complied smart contract's JSON object should be in a build file).

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't work? I see no obvious mistake, only that you are using the same source for all compilations.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57464939/solidity-how-to-compile-multiple-smart-contracts-in-compile-js-file)